# AEM6.4: Meaning of values in image map properties

Tags: aem, imagemap

AEM offers a plugin to create image maps for its internal inplace editor. After configuration the given values are stored into follow forrmat:

```
[rect(89,92,356,368)"/content/sites/we-retail/us"|"_blank"|"fdfdfdfdf"|(0.2,0.2004,0.8,0.8017)]
```

The first paratheses are defines the coordinates of choosen shape.
The content within the first quotaion signs defines the target site, within the second how to open it the browser. In the third pair of quotations sign contains an alternative Text for non images display.

What I don't know are the values in second paratheses. Does someone know for what these values stands for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [WCM core components Image model](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/models/v2/ImageImpl.java), they are called relative coordinates.

They are not standard HTML attributes and are instead populated as data attributes of the area tag within [the image component](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v2/image/image.html).

See code below:

```
<area shape="${area.shape}" coords="${area.coordinates}" href="${area.href}" 
      target="${area.target}" alt="${area.alt}" data-cmp-hook-image="area" 
      data-cmp-relcoords="${area.relativeCoordinates}">
```

Since the map coordinates are fixed coordinates and do not change when the image scales in or not based on screen sizes, the image component’s JavaScript uses this relative coordinates data to adjust the coordinates of the map area whenever the image size is adjusted. This is handled by the `resizeAreas()` function within the component’s [clientlib](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v2/image/clientlibs/site/js/image.js).